# How to install m23 server on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt

I would like to use m23 to maintain a cluster of other Ubuntu machines, but unfortunately I can't find any documentation how to install m23 server on an Ubuntu machine. Neither are there any packages for Ubuntu.

Does anybody know how to install m23 on an Ubuntu machine?

UPDATE: The Debian source does not work for Ubuntu

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 m23 : Depends: apache-common ist aber nicht but is not going to be installed
                      apache2.2-common ist but is not going to be installed
```

That is strange, because of the fact that apache is installed. What ever, trying to install the package leads to an error:

```
Package 'apache-common' has no installation candidate
```

I think, the problem is, that the packages in Ubuntu have a different name. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so, because I don't want to know how you generally can solve the problem of a missing package, but I would like to know, how to install m23 on an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: the duplicate is *not* about installing a missing package it is about **unmet dependencies** stopping a package from being installed, which is the first line of your error "The following packages have unmet dependencies:" there are a multitude of answers to the duplicate question that should help....BTW to get m23 to install you will need to install the packages listed as dependencies, hence you will need to "solve the problem of a missing package" if the duplicate does not help, eidt you question to include why it does not

Comment: @TrailRider Ok, I edited my question.

Comment: answer is untested so please confirm if the steps work ;-)

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install apache-common` helps?

Comment: @Braiam No, it does not. Updated the question.

Comment: try this command `sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude install m23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m23 is not intended for use on Ubuntu as m23 server. There are too many dependencies on Debian system things for it to run on a derivate of Debian, which differs in crucial parts from Debian (like Ubuntu).

You would have to re-write m23 in some parts to make it run on a Ubuntu machine.

For this reason, the m23 packages won't install on Ubuntu. m23 even checks if the machine you plan to install it on is a Debian machine, and it won't start if it is on Ubuntu.

You can, however, install m23 in a VM on your Ubuntu machine. Or you can set up a Debian server for m23. You could even install m23 on a Raspberry Pi, or in a CloudStack environment. But always on Debian.

And of course, you can manage Ubuntu machines using your m23 server.

If you have questions, you can also always ask in the m23 forum - I guess questions about m23 might be answered faster and more complete there by the people who write m23 (like me, I found your question by accident).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that. It is of cause a pity. As it does not make sense for me to set up an Debian Server for the environment I would like to use m23 in, I can't use it at all. A VM is not a handy solution, in my opinion. How ever,  Debian may be the best distribution for servers generally, but it would be nice to be able to use m23 server on other distributions too. Because sometimes you can't choose...

Comment: You're right about that ;-) - but we just don't have the resources to make these changes. Of course, there is always the option to pay someone to change m23 (no advertisement intended, only to give the last possibility!) - or you could take a look at opsi, FAI, maybe FusionDirectory or (R)?ex. I think they are available for Ubuntu, too - and maybe they also do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this on the m23 website for installing it in Debian](http://m23.sourceforge.net/PostNuke-0.750/html/index.php?id=1000000175&currentpath=home#deb).

> The packages are stored on the SourceForge server and can be installed
>   via APT. The following steps must be done as root:
>
> Import the GPG key with
>
> ```
> wget -T1 -t1 -q http://m23.sourceforge.net/m23-Sign-Key.asc -O - | apt-key add -
> ```
>
> to ensure the integrity of the m23 packages.
>
> Add
>
> ```
> deb http://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/m23/m23inst ./
> ```
>
> in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.
>
> Run
>       apt-get update
>
> And install m23 with
>
> ```
> apt-get install m23
> ```
>
> Let all software get configured automatically ("yes"), beside you are
>   really knowing what you are doing.
>
> Make sure that the network interface (`eth0`, `eth1`, ...), that will be
>   used for communication between your m23 server and the m23 clients, is
>   the first in the list of the interfaces shown in
>   `/etc/network/interface`s and has a static IP address. This is required
>   to ensure correct communication.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work. I updated my question.

Comment: Install the dependencies and try again ;-)

Comment: Sure, that would be easy, but is not working. I Updated my question.